# Get a list of directories in R in order

Tags: r, file, directory

I'm trying to get a list of directories in R. I ran the following code and I sort of got what I wanted except for one hitch, R didn't list it in order. It shows me a numbered list but in the order of 1,3,5,7 etc and lists two folders beside each other. I want to know how to get a list with one folder name per line. I attached a picture for reference[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj9YH.jpg)

Comment: What you are seeing it is just the preview of the data in RStudio. Your list is already "one folder name per line", if you wanna check that in Rstudio you could transform it in a dataframe with `newlist<-as.data.frame(oldlist)` or maybe `newlist<-t(as.data.frame(oldlist))`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really new to R and I did not know that what I was seeing was just a preview of the data. I have already tried saving my results as data frames but I never thought to do it for this particular scenario. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default in R to print a vector. If you want to format it otherwise, you need to use something like `writeLines(list.dirs("c:/"))`

```r
# vectror printing
letters[1:10]
#>  [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

# formatted printing
writeLines(letters[1:10])
#> a
#> b
#> c
#> d
#> e
#> f
#> g
#> h
#> i
#> j
```

Comment: This is even better than what I was expecting because now I get a list without the numbers before the folder/file names ( [1] ) thanks so much!